# create.js.erb show its code on browser instead of execute code

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I am using ruby 1.8.7 and rails 2.3.11.  I have a simple form, and I want to put some ajax in create.js.erb:

```
alert('call from ajax');
```

In my controller, I change the create action:

```
def create
  @weburl = Weburl.new(params[:weburl])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @weburl.save
      format.js
      format.html { redirect_to(@weburl, :notice => 'Weburl was successfully created.') }
    else
      format.html { render :action => "new" }
      format.xml  { render :xml => @weburl.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

my form partial

```
<% form_remote_for(weburl) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_messages %>

  <p>
    <%= f.label :url %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :url %>
  </p>
  <p>
   <%= f.submit 'Save' %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

and my new.html.erb file is

```
<h1>New weburl</h1>
<%= render :partial => 'form', :locals=>{:weburl=>@weburl}%>
<%= link_to 'Back', weburls_path %>
```

When I submit the form, it shows on the browser:

```
alert('call from ajax');
```

instead of javascript popup alert message.

Comment: Can you show the code that submits the form? And also output of the post request in rails log?

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more code. What the problem is, your javascript code is not executing at client side. If possible put the response in eval(). check out this [w3schools tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) :